# Native-Base Icon at the start of the button and text centered

Tags: react-native, native-base

Hello everyone I'm trying to create the button I would show below in my screenshots. My first screenshot is what I have right now and my second is what I want. Trying for hours to put my icon at the start. Found out I can use flex-start on my button but then I can not centered my text any tips? (I'm using the Native-Base Library)

```js
<Button variant="outline" size="lg" justifyContent="center">
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <Icon as={MailIcon} />
            <Text size="sm">Sign Up With Email</Text>
    </View>
</Button>
```

[image]

[image]

I need it to be responsive since we have multiple phone devices with different resolutions.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have used TouchableOpacity but you can use it for button.

Here i share my code & style below, this will solve your problem:

```
<View style={styles.btn_view}>
            <TouchableOpacity[![enter image description here][1]][1]
              style={styles.button}
                <Icon size={30} name='time'/>
              <Text style={styles.text_inside_btn}>Set Seconds</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
```

```
btn_view: {
    width: '60%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 15,
    height: 50,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 10,
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
  text_inside_btn: {
    width: '90%',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for the response is it possible use native-base components?